# How to display a String variable in text field python

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to display the variable string in a text field.  i am using this function

```
def buttonClick():
    file_path = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Android Application Files", ".apk"), ("All files", "*.*")))
    print file_path
```

now i want this file_path to be printed in this text field

```
self.fnameEntry = StringVar()
self.fnameEntry = Entry(textvariable=self.fnameEntry)
self.fnameEntry.grid(row=4, column=0) #sticky=E)
```

How do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this

```
self.fnameVar = StringVar()
self.fnameEntry = Entry(textvariable=self.fnameVar)
self.fnameVar.set(file_path)
```

Comment: i tried this it didnt work because my file_path variable is inside a function and we are accessing it outside function scope. 
so i need some other logic for this. im confused

Comment: If you want to see the file_path variable in the entry field, you need to call the stringvar's `set()` method with the file_path as argument. If you don't do this in the scope where the file_path is available, then you must store the file_path somewhere during the buttonclick.

Comment: can you provide a sample code how to do that ? store file_path during buttonclick ?

Comment: Well, `some_variable = file_path`, or `some_dict['foo'] = file_path`.